# Where do I get source code for the Composite C1 Facebook ImageGallery module?

Tags: c1-cms

I found the source code for Composite C1 CMS on CodePlex, but I have not been able to find the source code for the various modules published by Composite C1. I particularly need the source code for the Facebook ImageGallery module, as it seems to only pull 25 photos per album. I'm confident that a with a couple of additional parameters and some changes to the XSLT that calls the C# functions, I could either allow more photos to be returned for each album or include a "Next" link to show the next group of 25 photos.

Comment: http://compositec1contrib.codeplex.com/ or http://c1packages.codeplex.com/ maybe ?

Comment: The answer is c1packages.codeplex.com. For some reason I didn't realize it had a different source repository than the normal composite site. Change your comment to an answer @Rufinus and I'll accept it.

Comment: give it to mawtex, i nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code for Composite C1 packages / contributions can be found here:

- http://c1packages.codeplex.com/
- http://compositec1contrib.codeplex.com/

The Facebook Image Gallery ([Composite.Media.ImageGallery.Facebook](http://docs.composite.net/Composite.Media.ImageGallery.Facebook)) source code is on the [C1Packages CodePlex site](http://c1packages.codeplex.com/). Browse source code and locate the folder "Composite.Media.ImageGallery.Facebook".

Comment: Correct, although points would have been given to the answer: "in the App_Code folder of your site already".

Comment: @JohnBledsoe this is true for the current package, but its not a guarantee that all packages put their code in App_Code. Specially the Contrib-project uses dedicated dll's for everything.